# C++ Handling big numbers

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

Okay, I have to do simple task for my c++ class. Two functions, first is Fibonacci sequence, second some random sequence (finding `e`). It looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

void fib(int number)
{
    int a=0, b=1;
    printf("%d\n", a); 
    for (; number>0; number--)
    {
        printf("%d\n", b);
        b+=a;
        a = b-a;
    }
}

void e_math(unsigned int number)
{
    for (double n = 1; number>0; number--, n++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", pow((1+1/n), n));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (std::string(argv[2])=="f") fib(atoi(argv[1])-1);
    if (std::string(argv[2])=="c") e_math(atoi(argv[1])-1);
    else printf("Bad argument\n");
}
```

So at the end I did `g++ main.cpp -o app;./app 10 f`. It worked perfectly. But when I thought: Hmm, maybe lets check for bigger number, and added 50 it just messed up. I mean it did good for about 40 sequence numbers (checked with Python), but then it started to `printf()` negatives etc. I figured it's probably about `int` range. So I changed `int a=0, b=1` to `long long a=0, b=1`, but still it prints the same (I still use `printf("%d..)`, because `%lld` does not work

Comment: Consider using `<iostream>` and `std::cout` to display something in C++, instead of printf

Comment: Try using %I64d specifier. But you will get the same overflow problem say on N = 100.

Comment: `%lld` does work (at least with my compiler).

Comment: Your problem is using `%d` to print something that is not a plain `int`. It seems you already found the correct way, why would you not use it?

Comment: Okay, `std::cout` works, but what I'm obligated to do it in `printf()`?

And a second thing. It worked, but only for something like 80+ numbers. In Python I could do 300 without any problems. Can I do it in C++?

Comment: @Frynio: If you're obligated to use `printf` why would you say you're using C++ and not just C

Comment: @Frynio: python uses arbitrarily large integers by default. In C++, integer types like `unsigned int` or `unsigned long long int` are limited to a certain number of bits (e.g: 32, 64) and therefore cannot represent integers bigger than 2^32 or 2^64. To go further, you need to use custom types able to handle larger integers or even arbitrarily large integers. My answer mentions `boost::multiprecision` that offers both alternatives (integers on 128, 256, 512 ... bits or arbitrarily large integers using gmp library).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are information in comments telling you how to be able to print `long long` correctly so that you can benefit from the whole range. However, as said blazs in his answer, you will not go much further (it will cycle for n=94 on unsigned 64 bits).

If you want to handle much bigger Fibonacci numbers (in fact, arbitrary large numbers) you can use [boost::multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html).

For example:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>  

boost::multiprecision::mpz_int fib(boost::multiprecision::mpz_int number)
{
    boost::multiprecision::mpz_int a=0, b=1;
    for (; number>0; number--)
    {
        b += a;
        a = b-a;
    }
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << fib(500);
}
```

You'll need to link with gmp when building. For example:

```
g++ -o fib fib.cc -lgmp
./fib
139423224561697880139724382870407283950070256587697307264108962948325571622863290691557658876222521294125
```

Answer (score 2):

The `n`th [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is around `1.6^n` which for `n=50` is a big number (it's `53316291173`). You may be able to represnet it as `long`, but as the thing grows exponentially, you won't be able to store `Fn` for large `n` into a primitive data type (where `Fn` denotes the `n`th Fibonacci number): the `n+1`th Fibonacci number is roughly 1.6 times the `n`th Fibonacci number.

You need a big int data type to compute `Fn` for large `n`.

Comment: 1.6^50 is much smaller than 2^63 (you can tell even without calculating because both the values are larger), and therefore will easily fit in `int64_t`.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. :) But the thing grows exponentially, so if you increase `n` just a little, it will be too big.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Integer classes from [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org).  Here the link to the [C++ Interface](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface).

Edit: Also look at [15.7.4 Fibonacci Numbers](https://gmplib.org/manual/Fibonacci-Numbers-Algorithm.html).

Comment: Or in C++, `boost::multiprecision` wrapper for GMP: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html

Comment: @ColinPitrat That's nice.  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Since %lld is not portable and does not work in any compiler, what about if you declare *a* and *b* as long and print the result with c++ std::cout?

This is necessary since the 50th Fibonacci number is 7778742049, which is bigger than the typical max positive integer value (32 bits) that is 2147483647.

By the way, you should remove the last *else*, I don't think is doing what you want when the parameter f is provided.

Here is the [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cd6d4c5625d6948) working.